# How do I search for a specific word (in a single row) and answer with the value of the previous column, unspecific to position, with a formula

Tags: google-sheets, split, reference, match, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible on google sheets to be able to do this?

I have information on a single row (it is not organised via columns), I want to specify a search formula to find information and return the previous cells (one column to the left) value.

For Example..

A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6

I want to search for A5, to return A4.

I've tried Vlookup, hlookup, etcetc, but I can't seem to get my head around it if the information isn't organised via columns.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IFNA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(I1, A1:1, 0)-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a correct answer since only cell A1 contains : A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6. The data needs to be splitted first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **split** the input string and then use **index** & **match** to locate the desire element.

Here is the solution:

```
=INDEX(split(A1," | "),IF(MATCH("A5",split(A1," | "))-1=0,1,MATCH("A5",split(A1," | "))-1))
```

**Explanation:**

- A1 is the cell that contains this text: A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6
- A5 is the element you want to look for

The result will be A4 since you want the previous element.

Note that if you search for A1 then it will just give you A1 because there is no element before A1.

[image: Explanation]

> **References**:

- [split()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [index()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)